# How to add smart controller to ceiling fan with single switched hot

Tags: home-automation

I want a WiFi connected smart controller for my ceiling fans. They are all wired with a single switched hot, so I cannot use a replacement smart switch alone. Are there any wall mounted switches that work nicely with a ceiling mounted controller?

Desired features:

- Separate wall mounted switch and ceiling mounted controller
- Light dimmer
- 3-speed fan control
- WiFi
- Google Assistant compatible

Comment: Are you OK with having a bridge between your WiFi and another sort of home automation system?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Not preferable, but I am open to it.